# Use of SQL Server with DDD in ASP.Net Web App

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, .net, domain-driven-design

Hi I need to develop a new web application for my company and I must use DDD as per my senior-dev requirement.

In addition I'm maintaining (adding new features and fixing bugs) a large brownfield web app (FinTech app) that was developed by senior developers 5 years ago before I got in this company, as I only spent 1 year and half in this company.

This large web app I'm maintaining is architected using DDD with NoSQL (MongoDB) database for scalability and I also use this app as example when learning DDD.

*Now I have a new requirement to develop a web app using DDD coupled with SQL Server database only.
I already started modeling the database tables, but I'm stuck in the implementation of the SQL Server database in DDD - C# code .*

Indeed my bounded contexts is similar to the one on page 124 of this book written by [Microsoft Authors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735685355) (Dino and Andrea) with the same entities and values per each bounded context.
I have two bounded contexts (**BackOffice** and **ClientSite**) with same entites/values objects as in the book/picture.

**My concern is :**

*1) Do I really need to create 8 tables in Sql Server, then create aggregates in the repository to update them according to their bounded context as I have two bounded contexts?

2) Do I need to use Event-driving to update the other bounded-context too (**Backoffice**) if one bounded context is udpated?(like **ClientSite**) as both form a context-map

3) As per CQRS, what methods do I need to create in the aggregate for each bounded context, As I know I need save and delete command; and View (Query)

4) Do I need to create the same method for each aggregate? Is it not a violation of DRY principle?*

**I please just want you to confirm if it's right what I'm doing as I'm not an expert in DDD.**

EDIT :

The requirement I've got from the domain expert is : They need an application to manage the recruitment process for its recruitment agency.
they are opening a small local recruitment agency and they need a web app to manage the whole process.

So he told me they will have recruitment Agents for each Area (IT, Finance, Mechanics, Telecom, Medical...) and the backoffice to control everything/the whole process the recruitment agents are doing in the app.

**The process will be as follow :** 
*1) Backoffice will get request from a company to publish a job offer for x position(x area - let assume A company looking for a junior financial)

2) Backoffice forwards it to the relevant recruitment agent (financial in this case)

3) The recruit agent in charge of financial recruitment publishes the ad online, and manage it (sort all the submitted resume and select some candidates for interview)

4) If the candidate succeeds the interview then they give him an offer.*

[image]

Comment: "I must use DDD as per my senior-dev requirement" - this may be tricky to give a good answer to, depending on what conceptions or misconceptions your senior colleagues have about DDD, and on how much influence they'll exert over your code. For starters, DDD is not an architecture, but an approach to understanding the domain, modeling it, incorporating that model into the code, and evolving the code (refining aspects of the model over time), and it's supposed to be done collaboratively by the whole team, with a number of domain experts involved.

Comment: Now, you say you have two bounded contexts (BCs). Why? How did you arrive at them? What specific problem do they solve for you? On page 122, at the start of the section, there's this: "In the beginning, you assume one indivisible business domain [i.e, single context, remark by me] and start processing requirements to learn as much as possible about it and build the ubiquitous language." There's a common misconception about bounded contexts; they aren't supposed to be such a finely grained thing; e.g. if there's another BC, a whole different team may be working on it.

Comment: So you don't start with identifying bounded contexts; you can really do that only when you understand the dynamics of your domain really well, and how it affects the complexity and maintainability of your application (BCs are a way of addressing that). IMO, you should forget about BCs for now, and focus on what these two aspects of your application need to do, how they'll be used, what needs to be synchronized with what and how soon, etc.

Comment: E.g. investigate what problems you may face when different users are accessing, changing and saving data simultaneously, what invariants your need to maintain when processing these entities, and how aggregates may help manage that. Take that code that does various checks, and place it into an various aggregate roots as appropriate. Don't have the mindset that you *have* to do something because DDD supposedly mandates it; instead, you apply some approach to solve a problem. P.S. And don't be afraid to ask your senior colegues for clarification when you get stuck.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thank you so much for taking your time to help me out. I really appreciated that. Indeed I edited the question and added the small requirement he gave me regarding that recruitment application.  **By the way, why many folks are not replying. Am I in the right place/forum? did I use the right tags?**

Comment: @FilipMilovanović  `Now, you say you have two bounded contexts (BCs). Why? How did you arrive at them? What specific problem do they solve for you?`   I used **Conway's Law** to identify the bounded context

Comment: `what problems you may face when different users are accessing, changing and saving data simultaneously,`  I don't think here it really will be a problem as each recruitment agent will have his/her own account in the system and his own data in the system. A simple analogy of MS Windows, even if 3 people using the same physical computer but they have different accounts.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I also identify Bounded-Context using business-capability.

Comment: @KaseSpeakman Can you please help me out?
I also identify Bounded-Context using business-capability.